# Resat-native -Error-during installing Routing module

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native, I want to install a routing module.

Below is the snippet for my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View,Alert } from 'react-native';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  Button,
  ImageBackground,
  Router,
  Stack,
  Scene,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Home from './component/Home'
import About from './component/About'
export default class App extends Component {  
    render() {  
        return (  
          <View >
          <Router>
            <Stack key="root">
              <Scene key="login" component={Home} title="home" />
              <Scene key="register" component={About} title="about" />
            </Stack>
          </Router>
        </View>
        );  
    }  
}
```

The error while installing is shown below kindly help me to solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You likely forgot a step in the installation process. If you have not required `react-native-screens` then do `npm install react-native-screens` since it is a dependency of `react-native-router-flux`.